# override temp Path environment variable for only one exe, windows 2008

Tags: windows, path, windows-server-2008, environment-variables

I have a c# application that references System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() to determine a storage path.  I would like to modify the file write path for thie one app without changing any environment variables for other applications.  Running windows server 2008.  Any ideas?

Edit: this is a running application I would prefer not to rebuild.  Can this be done via script or command?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable().  Changes like that only have an affect for the current process.  Just replacing the code that uses GetTempPath() is of course the much better solution.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Let me rephrase the question.  Can this be done without a rebuild?